# Array to String Conversion Exception while running db seed at Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, seed

I want to fill my database with fake data but when I run seed command it keeps giving me Array To String Conversion Exception I know Its because some function but i can not detect which one? 
I tried using $faker->word property instead of name but same problem

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'verified' => $verified = $faker->randomElements([User::VERIFIED_USER, User::UNVERIFIED_USER]),
        'verification_token' => $verified == User::VERIFIED_USER ? null : User::generateVerficationCode(),
        'admin' => $faker->randomElements([User::REGULAR_USER, User::ADMIN_USER]),
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => 
    '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
        'remember_token' => Str::random(1, 10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(Category::class, function(Faker $faker){
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

and Here is my Database Seeder class function

```
public function run()
{
    DB::statement('set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

    User::truncate();
    Category::truncate();
    Product::truncate();
    Transaction::truncate();

    DB::table('category_product')->truncate();

    $userQuantity = 200;
    $categoriesQuantity = 50;
    $productsQuantity = 1000;
    $transactionQuantity = 1000;

    factory(User::class, $userQuantity)->create();

    factory(Category::class, $categoriesQuantity)->create();

    factory(Product::class, $productsQuantity)->create()->each(function($product) {

        $categories = Category::all()->random(mt_rand(1, 5))->pluck('id')->all();

        $product->categories()->attach($categories);

    });

    factory(Transaction::class, $transactionQuantity)->create();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$faker->randomElements()` is giving you an array. What you want is `$faker->randomElement()` that will pick just one element from the array you provide.

Comment: Thanks you it solves the problem but there is another one raised ( unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Transaction]